# How to insert Jupyter Notebook syntax into a question

Tags: support

I'm trying to format my question so that the body contains an exact replica of what my Jupyter Notebook shows (with the `In [1]:`, `In [2]:`, ... cell structure).

[image]

How can I do the above in the body of a SO question? I'd prefer this to a screenshot so that the code is copyable.

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere (I didn't see) or if there are nice example questions which have this (I didn't find).

Comment: do you also mean the grey boxes and the specific code highlighting and image placement? The answer would be disappointing: you can't get that exactly because we're limited in the html we can can use.

Comment: Here is a similar question on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295700/easy-way-to-post-my-jupyter-notebook-output-in-a-stack-overflow-post)

Comment: I did not checked myself but it could be (I'm not sure) to copy-paste as html. Open Developer Tools in your browser, find an element that corresponds to jupyter cell, copy inner html, paste it. Recipe is not for faint-hearted but in theory it must work

Comment: **UPDATE**: I just checked myself, sad but this recipe is very limited. It was not possible to paste output with graphs